# Method with combinations of different argument types

Tags: c#

I'm wondering if its possible to write a C# method that can take a combination of different argument types.

For example, this method would combine four overloaded methods into one.

```
public static void MyMethod( (JObject or File) jsonOne, (JObject or File) jsonTwo) {}
```

Comment: What's the benefit? Provide multiple overloads  with different signatures.

Comment: Internally you'd have to write code to figure out what type each parameter was and deal with it appropriately, at that point you may as well have the separate method overloads anyway.

Comment: `JObject` and `File` classes has pretty different members and doesn't implements any common interface. So this "combined" method will be full of spaghetti code like `if (jsonOne is File) {.....} else if (isonOne is JObject) { ... }`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Imagine there's a 3rd parameter like the first two, now you're up to *8* overloads.  Now what if there's a 4th, you're up to *16* overloads.  It scales exponentially, rather than linearly.

Comment: Technically you could do `MyMethod(object jasonOne, object jasonTwo)` and then just do all the type checking you'd have to do anyway.

Comment: @Servy understands my problem. The question is generic and doesnt go into depth about my specific problem..

Comment: @juharr With the OP's solution you'd have to just as much type checking as with yours, yes, but the difference is that the OP's (non-existent) solution *would* guarantee that whatever the actual types are, they're valid types.  Your solution would not, so your solution is no more work than his would be, but it loses all static type safety.  Also relevantly, the caller of the code would have no good way of knowing what to pass in, making it not only possible, but rather easy, to write incorrect code.

Comment: @Servy: since OP uses always the same type and similar parameter names(one,two,...) i think the best way would be to provide an `IEnumerable<JObject>` and an `IEnumerable<JFile>` overload. Then it can be used for a single object/file and also for multiple.

Comment: If all you're doing here is reading the `File` in as a `JObject` then I'd say just require `JObject` and force the caller to do the `File` to `JObject` parsing.

Comment: @TimSchmelter That forces all parameters to be of the same type, it also assumes that any number of parameters is valid, neither assumption seems to be appropriate in this case.

Comment: @Servy: why do you know what's appropriate in this case? You're also making assumptions aren't you? This question is too generic to be answered without being _opionion based_.

Comment: It's not that generic. I think @Servy is right in that its one Object type or the other, but they are singular objects. In my case I will have upwards of 16 overloaded methods to do this work.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I made the assumption that I couldn't make additional assumptions, yes.  That is technically an assumption, I suppose.  I was merely saying that you were making assumptions not granted from the question; if the OP can confirm those assumptions are valid, then that's fine.  What assumption(s) do you feel that I've made about the question?

Comment: @Servy: i haven't made the assumption that any number is valid. By providing an `IEnumerable<T>`(or `IList<T>`) method parameter you're not allowing any number. You're just allowing to pass one or multiple. You could  throw an exception if you get too many. The overload(or new method) approach is making less assumptions than the new type approach. Introducing a new type which holds two properties suggests that they are related or even belong together.

Comment: @TimSchmelter By providing an `IEnumerable` you're removing static verification of the correct number of arguments.  You are correct, it's technically not allowing any number; it can't be negative or fractional.  It's allowing any *whole* number (and also an infinite number), even if that number isn't valid.  Creating a new type to compose values of two different types doesn't really make any more or less assumptions about their relationship than having multiple overloads where those types are considered interchangeable.  It doesn't *require* (or *assume*) anything of their relationship.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Since the idea of creating a new type that composes these two types really bothers you, I've edited my solution such that there is no longer any new type that refers to both of those types explicitly.

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot create a single method overload that can accept one of two fixed types for a given parameter.

The best you could do (while still avoiding multiple overloads) is to create a new type, which you could create an instance of through one of two different types, and accept an instance of *that*.

```
public class MyJSON
{
    public MyJSON(JObject json)
    {
        FirstOption = json;
        FirstOptionValid = true;
    }
    public MyJSON(File json)
    {
        SecondOption = json;
        SecondOptionValid = true;
    }
    public JObject FirstOption { get; private set; }
    public bool FirstOptionValid { get; private set; }
    public File SecondOption { get; private set; }
    public bool SecondOptionValid { get; private set; }

    public static implicit operator MyJSON(File json)
    {
        return new MyJSON(json);
    }
    public static implicit operator MyJSON(JObject json)
    {
        return new MyJSON(json);
    }
}
```

You could even create implicit conversions from `JObject` and `File` to `MyJSON` so that a user can actually pass a `JObject` or `File` object to `MyMethod`, without even needing to explicitly construct an intermediary object at all.

In fact, it's actually very easy to generalize this for any fixed number of types by using generics:

```
public class Option<T1, T2>
{
    public Option(T1 value)
    {
        FirstOption = value;
        FirstOptionValid = true;
    }
    public Option(T2 value)
    {
        SecondOption = value;
        SecondOptionValid = true;
    }
    public T1 FirstOption { get; private set; }
    public bool FirstOptionValid { get; private set; }
    public T2 SecondOption { get; private set; }
    public bool SecondOptionValid { get; private set; }

    public static implicit operator Option<T1, T2>(T2 value)
    {
        return new Option<T1, T2>(value);
    }
    public static implicit operator Option<T1, T2>(T1 value)
    {
        return new Option<T1, T2>(value);
    }
}
```

We can now write your method as:

```
public static void MyMethod(Option<JObject, File> json1, Option<JObject, File> json2)
```

Comment: This, although as has already been mentioned it would make much more sense to have multiple overloads with different signatures for each type required.

Comment: @GJKH That depends on the situation.  Multiple overloads would be fine for one parameter with two options, but it scales exponentially with both the number of options for any given parameter and the number of parameters, while this scales linearly, so if there's more than a few types, or more than a few parameters, this would likely be easier.

Comment: This could be expanded such that `MyJSON` exposes whatever the method needs from these two types in such a way that you don't have to know if it was create from a `JObject` or `File`.  But really that depends on exactly how differently the method treats them.

Comment: @juharr Correct.  Without context of how the method uses it, we couldn't say if more could be done.

Comment: This suggests that `JObject` and `File` are related somehow. I normally don't create new types to avoid another method overload. That introduces another layer, the type must also be known from wherever the method is called(f.e. via webservice). Since OP uses `jsonOne`,`jsonTwo`, `...` it sounds as if he could simply provide a `IEnumerable<JObject>` and `IEnumerable<File>`  overload.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It's not a particularly uncommon practice to utilize new objects purely for the sake of simplifying method overloads, but you are correct that in most cases there is simply no need to, as multiple overloads typically solve that problem sufficiently well.  In this case, multiple overloads is technically capable of solving the problem, but does so poorly; more poorly than creating new objects would (after a certain scale) so it's a solution to at least consider.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The question specifically asked to create a method where a given parameter could be one of a fixed list of types.  If you feel that the OP can avoid needing to solve that problem, then by all means ask them for the additional context that you would need to determine if that would solve their actual problem.  What that solution *wouldn't* do is answer the question that they asked.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible, but dirty solutions:

One (accepting objects and typechecking)

```
public static void MyMethod(object one, object two)
{
    if(one is JObject) // handle
    else if(one is File) // handle
    else throw SomeException();
    ...
```

same for the second param

Two: optional params

```
public static void MyMethod(JObject jone = null, File fone = null, 
    JObject jtwo = null, File ftwo = null)
{ 
    if(jone == null && fone == null)
        throw SomeException();
    else
        // use set values and do stuff
    ...
```

Comment: yes, the dots should indicate that... you have to do it for every param, I omitted the second part.

Comment: Note that *both* of these solutions lose static type safety, the first losing all type safety entirely, making the method *extremely* difficult to use properly, and the second not being able to enforce the constraint that only one of each pair of objects should have a value (As well as effectively meaning `null` can never be a valid value, which may not be a correct assumption.)   It also scales *very* poorly with the number of possible types for each parameter, and would be even more confusing for a caller if the type options for each parameter aren't the same.

Comment: Dynamic is another option similar to object.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov What would that possibly add here?

Comment: Yes, the answer is definitely not perfect, but I think that there is no perfect answer here. Yours is pretty close though, didn't think of that ;-)

Comment: @Servy `dynamic` could let OP write JavaScript-like code in C# which may be the goal (like in ["you can write FORTRAN code in any language"](http://blog.codinghorror.com/you-can-write-fortran-in-any-language/)). It probably not going to help if objects are of very different types like in OP's sample, but an option to consider if generics/base classes don't work out. I don't expect OP to be so lazy to just dive into that suggestion so and read on drawback first as there are plenty...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, I'm familiar with what `dynamic` does.  As you said, it doesn't help here at all as there isn't a common API being used for the two types.  If the types would actually have exactly the same API, even if they didn't share a base class, then the solution would be to use an interface.  Given that the types are known at compile time there's no need for, and in fact much harm to come of, dynamic typing.  `dynamic` would be useful if the method wouldn't even know what types would be calling it, just that they'd have a method matching a given signature.

Answer (score 1):

See code below:

```
interface IDo {
   void DoSomething();
}

class MyFile : File, IDo {
   void DoSomething() {
       // blah blah
   }
}

class MyJObject : JObject, IDo {
   void DoSomething() {
       // blah blah
   }
}

public static void MyMethod<T1, T2>(T1 one, T2 two)
    where T1 : IDo
    where T2 : IDo
{
   one.DoSomething();
   two.DoSomething();
}
```

If File and/or JObject are sealed, then use containment instead of inheritance:

```
class MyFile : IDo {
   File file;
   void DoSomething() {
       // blah blah
   }
}

class MyJObject : IDo {
   JObject jObject;
   void DoSomething() {
       // blah blah
   }
}
```